# Row and column that matches with 2 table in excel

Tags: excel

Having a table as below:

[image: img]

Need to fill the value based on row and column

[image: output]

output expected

[image]

Comment: INDEX/MATCH/MATCH will do this.

Comment: Can you help me? I don't know how to write the formula?

Comment: https://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/